# C segmentation fault array of struct

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, hashtable

I am working in a big project and I am getting segmentation fault in the below scenario. If anyone can say the possible causes of the issue it will be great. Thanks.

I have two structures,

```
struct HashElt
{
  char* url;
  float pageRank;
  char* token;
  struct HashElt* next;
};

struct HTable
{
  struct HashElt* table[2000]; 
};
```

The table variable in the HTable contains HashElt struct, which is a node in the linked list. When I try to link a new HashElt to to the already existing one in table variable , I am getting segmentation fault.

```
if(table->table[i] == NULL)
 table->table[i] = elt;
else
{ struct HashElt* currElt;
currElt = table->table[i];

while(currElt != NULL)
{ if(currElt == elt) return;
  currElt = currElt->next;
}
currElt->next = elt;
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault in this line, currElt->next = elt;
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `while(currElt != NULL)` -> `while(currElt->next != NULL)`

Comment: When you exit the loop `while(currElt != NULL)` what is the value of `currElt`?  What happens when you access `currElt->next`?

Comment: Seriously, what do you expect `currElt` to be after a `while (currElt != NULL)`?

Comment: The op have confused themselves with the formatting. And me.

Comment: btw, `while (currElt->next)` would do as well. I personally prefer that style, as `NULL` means semantically "no pointer", so it's naturally "falsey" ... but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Felix and MFisherKDX have answered this already. I wonder why not make an answer, but instead make a comment:).

Comment: @малинчекуров just because this error is too simple to deserve an answer. After all, questions and answers on SO should form a Q&A library helpful to future readers. I don't see that here, so voting to close as "no longer reproduceable / simple typo".

Comment: I sincerely hope this isn't the actual "indentation" scheme used in the large project.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Its university project and moreover they have used a similar indentation scheme in other parts of the project.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your mistakes, your while loop will break when `currElt` is `NULL` and in the statement `currElt->next = elt;` is equivalent to `NULL->next = elt` that means you are using a NULL pointer to access its value next and that is why you are getting the segmentation violation.

```
while(currElt != NULL)
{ 
    if(currElt == elt) return;
    currElt = currElt->next;
}
currElt->next = elt;
}
```

So change it like below, here loop will break once `currElt` is pointing to the last node and hence it is not null here.

```
while(currElt->next != NULL)
{ 
    if(currElt == elt) return;
    currElt = currElt->next;
}
  if(currElt == elt) return;
  currElt->next = elt;
}
```